# max limit of outgoing call to other services from nodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, http, concurrency

i'm still relatively new to NodeJS, but I'm interesting in making > 100k simultaneous connections to the API of several stock exchanges.

In the node [docs](http://blog.nodejs.org/2015/02/06/node-v0-12-0-stable/) it mentions that the number of simultaneous outgoing calls/connections is infinity - is that accurate?

Comment: There's likely some theoretical limit related to the resources available to your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This info on the changelog is more related to the fact that before the maximum number of concurrent sockets node could handle was set to `5` (it was changeable of course) but now it is set to `Infinity` by default.

This has nothing to do with the capacity of connexions an application can handle, that will be limited by the network's characteristics, the OS specifications, the available resources on the server, etc.

In short, you are looking at something (the blog post) that has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: thanks, what about any limits for calls from nodeJS to 5 different APIs at the same time

Comment: You can very well launch any amount of calls in parallel in node.js if that's the question.

Comment: yes thats what i mean, is there somewhere in the docs that explain that explicitly?

Comment: Check out the global agent: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_globalagent since it has a max sockets that can limit the number of concurrent requests. In Node 12 this is set to Infinity, but it used to be 5 by default.